# Administrative Tools lost

Tags: windows-xp, control-panel, admin-tools

I can't find any icon in my Administrative Tools folder. How I can restore them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never seen them deleted. Go to control panel and look for "Administrative tools".

If you cannot find them, then you can recreate shortcuts through the following (this is a complete list of all of them, not just Windows XP):

```
Active Directory Management  admgmt.msc
ADSI Edit  adsiedit.msc
Application Server  appsrv.msc
Authorization Manager  azman.msc
Certificates  certmgr.msc
Certificate Authority  certsrv.msc
Certificate Templates  certtmpl.msc
Indexing Service  ciadv.msc
Component Services  comexp.msc
Computer Management  compmgmt.msc
Default Domain Controller Security Settings  dcpol.msc
Device Manager  devmgmt.msc
Disk defragmenter  dfrg.msc
Distributed File System  dfsgui.msc
DHCP  dhcpmgmt.msc
Disk Management  diskmgmt.msc
DNS  dnsmgmt.msc
Active Directory Domains and Trusts  domain.msc
Default Domain Security Settings  dompol.msc
Active Directory Users and Computers  dsa.msc
Active Directory Sites and Services  dssite.msc
Event Viewer  eventvwr.msc
Exchange System Manager  Exchange System Manager.msc
File Server Management  filesvr.msc
Shared Folders  fsmgmt.msc
Microsoft Fax Service Manager  fxsadmin.msc
Group Policy  gpedit.msc
Group Policy Management  gpmc.msc
Internet Authentication Service  ias.msc
Internet Information Services  iis.msc
IP Address Management  ipaddrmgmt.msc
Local Users and Groups  lusrmgr.msc
.NET Configuration 1.1  mscorcfg.msc
Removable Storage  ntmsmgr.msc
Removable Storage Operator Requests  ntmsoprq.msc
Performance  perfmon.msc
Enterprise PKI  pkiview.msc
Public Key Management  pkmgmt.msc
Routing and Remote Access   rrasmgmt.msc
Remote Storage  rsadmin.msc
Resultant Set of Policy  rsop.msc
Active Directory Schema  schmmgmt.msc
Local Security Settings  secpol.msc
Services  services.msc
Sidwalk  sidwalk.msc
Task Scheduler tasksched.msc
Telephony  tapimgmt.msc
Terminal Services Configuration/Connections  tscc.msc
Remote Desktops  tsmmc.msc
UDDI Services Console  uddi.msc
Active Directory Users and Computers (Exchange version)  users and computers.msc
WINS  winsmgmt.msc
Windows Management Infrastructure (WMI)  wmimgmt.msc
Printer Management printmanagement.msc
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration mscorcfg.msc
```

If you just want the Windows XP **default** ones, here they are (I am just including ones that are valid in administrative tools, for example, while "Device Manager" can be accessed on its own, it is part of "Computer Management", so I will not list it):

```
Component Services  comexp.msc
Computer Management  compmgmt.msc
Event Viewer  eventvwr.msc
Internet Information Services  iis.msc (If you have it installed)
Performance  perfmon.msc
Local Security Settings  secpol.msc
Services  services.msc
Task Scheduler tasksched.msc
Printer Management printmanagement.msc
Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration mscorcfg.msc
```

Extras:

```
System Configuration - %windir%\system32\msconfig.exe
Windows Memory Diagnostics (Vista + 7?) - %windir%\system32\MdSched.exe
iSCSI Initiator - %windir%\system32\iscsicpl.exe
Data Sources (ODBC) - %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe
```

In addition, if they are simply not being shown, you can take a look at the Start menu properties (right click on the start menu, and click properties), then -

[image]

Comment: I think those are for windows server, I want the items for windows xp only, can you list them?

Comment: Well, they are the list of **all** the mmc components, some of them that are server related even work on xp and you may have fun - such as gpedit!

I will try to fish out some of the main ones and edit the answer for you.

Comment: Done, hope you enjoy!

Comment: @WilliamHilsum, Is that the full list of mscs? Are there still some other ones?

Comment: @Pacerier - there are many more and some of them don't exist any more... That list was the majority of them in 2009 - please note that third party apps also install them. This is just the majority of them from Windows desktop and server.

Comment: @WilliamHilsum, Where can we get a full list then?

Comment: Regarding "Active Directory Users and Computers... ": Is the file name really "users and computers.msc" (with spaces)? Or is it two files, "users.msc" and "computers.msc"? Or something else?