# How can I get a list of installed certificates on Windows?

Tags: windows, certificate, cryptography

I know I have some certificates installed on my Windows 7 machine. How can I see what they are, the nicknames they are known by, and browse detailed information (such as issuer and available usage)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In **Internet Explorer**:

Go to **Tools** <sub>(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)</sub> → **Internet Options** → **Content** → **Certificates**.

Answer (score 70):

Using PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:
```

Comment: Well what I like about this answer is that I know how to launch a power shell, but where the hell are the internet options?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala `inetcpl.cpl`

Comment: Shorter version: `gci -r cert:` . I don't know why Powershell users insist on such long ass camel+hyphen case command names.

Comment: @SalmanPK: As a matter of principle I *always* give the long versions of the commands in my answers. This isn't Code Golf, it's trying to be helpful. If you want shorter, you should use `ls -r cert:` anyway.

Answer (score 57):

Or run (`Start -> Run` or just hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>):

```
certmgr.msc
```

Comment: Related: [Full list of .msc's](http://superuser.com/questions/52245/administrative-tools-lost/52252#52252), including *certmgr.msc*, *certsrv.msc* and *certtmpl.msc*.

Comment: use `certlm.msc` to access the list of the `Locale Machine`

Answer (score 20):

Start **mmc** via Search files or Command Prompt:

Menu *File* → *Add/Remove Snap-In...* → *Add...* → *Certificates* → *Add* → *My User account* and/or *Computer account* → *Finish* → *Close* → *OK* → Browse.

Comment: good answer, but usage of MMC may be restricted by policy if your computer is managed by an employer or other establishment; I was able to use the answer from @tborychowski